# In chrome extension content-scripts, how can I redirect the current window to a different url and still have the script continue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write an extension that goes through my google voice inbox and gets all phone numbers that have ever contacted me. I would like to get these numbers and them output them to www.editpad.org.

The issue is if I try to redirect from www.google.com/voice to www.editpad.org, I am using

```
window.location.href = "www.editpad.org"
```

I have also tried using background scripts like:

```
//content script
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: "http://www.editpad.org"});

//background
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
sendREsponse(); });
```

However, once it redirects, it seems like the script stops running (console.log doesn't even work). I believe it's because editpad.org is not in my manifest.json for matching websites.

If I add it to my matching websites, then the script will redirect to editpad.org, but then it will re-run and refresh to itself over and over.

How can I redirect the page to this editpad.org and still continue the script from where it left off so that I could say, "once you're on this new page, start executing the following function"

My manifest:

```
{


"manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Whistle",
  "description": "This extension searches for all phone numbers found on a Google Voice account",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistence": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.google.com/voice/*"],
      "js": ["jQuery.js", "execute.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    sendREsponse();
});
```

Comment: The primary reason for having an extension is to be independent of and persist script execution beyond the current domain. If it's restarting when you redirect to a url in your manifest.json then you are too tightly coupled with the domain and it's events.

Comment: @Chris, you've guessed correctly. There are at least several similar/duplicate questions with answers, however, so try searching a bit more. In short, you should use a background script to provide the new content script with data to continue processing.

Comment: Can you post your manifest config with the background page?

Comment: @wOxxOm could you point a link to me?

Comment: @Chris try adding editpad to your matches and in background next to scripts property, add "persistent": false

Comment: @juvian I tried doing so without results. I posted the new manifest.

Comment: my bad, meant to put "persistent": true. @nick should be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file:

```
"persistent":true
```

which is the default value.  You need to send a message containing all of the numbers back to the background page.  Then when the new page loads you can send a message to the new content script containing all of the numbers.

```
//content script
var msg = []; // array containing your numbers
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name:"get_numbers", message: msg});

//background
var data = {};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
  if (message.name=== "get_numbers"){
    data["numbers"] = message.message;
  }
  else if(message.name === "request_numbers"){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {name: "delegate_message",numbers: data["numbers"});
    });
  }
});

//content script (either a separate script or the same one)
if (window.location.href === "www.editpad.org"){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name:"request_numbers"});
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
        if(request.name === 'delegate_message'){
          // do whatever with the the phone numbers
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to set the persistence to false? Also, at what point can I redirect my current url to editpad.org?

Comment: If you set persistent false, the program I outlined above will not run.  Persistent false turns your bg page into an event page, an event page is unloaded when a new page is loaded in the browser so all data being stored there will be lost.  It does not make sense for your problem to set it to false.

Comment: I still dont' understand how I can change the url from google.com/voice to editpad.org without having the script execute over and over.

Comment: Your script will execute over again, that is the purpose of a content script.  By keeping your bg page persistent you can store data there and access it regardless of what url you on.

Comment: I added the if statement in my answer which will only execute that block of code if there is a url match (you can control which part of the content script will be injected based on what the url is).  For more complicated, multipage extensions using separate content scripts, with separate matching parameters would be better.

Comment: where did we put persistant:true? manifest for background or content.js?